# F# & FsXaml for opening new xaml windows

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, f#

I am in the process of learning F# and find the FsEmptyWindowsApp that uses FsXaml really useful for throwing together a UI for f# system. One issue I just cannot seem to be able to overcome is opening a new window from my startup MainWindow.xaml. I have created a ChildWindow.xaml and created a type using XAML provider in FsXaml but when I

```
type MainView = XAML<"MainWindow.xaml", true>    
type ChildWindow = XAML<"ChildWindow.xaml",true>

type MainViewModel() as self = 
inherit ViewModelBase()

    ...        

    member x.NewChildWindowCommand = 
        new FunCommand ((fun action -> 
                        let cw = ChildWindow()
                        cw.Root.Activate() |> ignore
                       ),
                        (fun canExecute -> true))
```

I always get an error when I run the command stating "cannot locate resource ChildWindow.xaml", I have put it in the project above MainWindow.xaml with its own code behind and always get the, cannot locate resource error.

I have tried manually loading xaml using

```
Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/<asseblyname>;component;/ChildWindow.xaml",UriKind.Relative))
```

but once again same error regarding cannot locate resource...

Any help and explanation as to how I should be using XAML type provider (FxXaml) in FsEmptyWindowsApp to open a new window would be greatly appreciated. alternatively if anyone knows how to do page navigation with FsXaml that would be very useful. I have downloaded the Demos and non of them seem to cover multi-paged/-windowed demos

Comment: You didn't know Single Paged WPF applications was a thing? ;-) Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Comment: I have built many SPAs with asp.net & angular js now learning wpf... Do you know how to load and switch between UserControls in the same window? There is one Demo I have seen that covers Using a UserControl as an element in the Mainwindow.xaml but I have been unable to switch it to another UserControl. Do I have to set the content attribute of some root container to a XAML type provider root of the control? I still have the "cannot locate resource error trying to load the control xaml

Comment: Nah, I was just kidding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue, on the newly created xaml files you need to go into the properties and set build action to resource ... now everything works as expected, wish I had figured this out sooner as been evading me for weeks

Comment: Setting the type to "Resource" worked for me also. Can't you accept your own answer as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

In FsXaml 2.x opening a new window can be done as:

```
type ChildWindow = XAML<"ChildWindow.xaml">

//somewhere in the code
ChildWindow().Show()  //open, don't wait

ChildWindow().ShowDialog()  //open and wait
```

Solution file `ChildWindow.xaml` should have Build action set to 'Resource'.